# AWS Cloudfront: Is It Possible To Use One HTTPS Certificate to Cover example.com AND www.example.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

When I create an HTTPS certificate in AWS for `example.com` it works, and I can attach it to my Cloudfront just fine ... **IF** I set "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" to `example.com`.

Similarly, if I create a certificate for `*.example.com`, I can attach it to my Cloudfront ... **IF**  I set "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" to `www.example.com`.

Strangely though, if I try to use either certificate with a Cloudfront record for both Alternate Domains, I get:

> InvalidViewerCertificateException: The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add

Do I really need two certificates and two Cloudfront records just to cover the `www.` case also?  It seems like it should be possible to just have one certificate which supports a single Cloudfront record, and that record covers both `www.example.com` and `example.com`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can request a public certificate in ACM and add both `example.com` and `*.example.com` into the domain names field. The resulting certificate will be suitable for both of the CNAMEs in your CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Well duh, how incredibly obvious.  Somehow the AWS UI made me think I could only have one, but I can absolutely have both.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use multiple domains on a single SSL certificate.

Be aware as a caveat to this, it will not work for any browsers that do no support SNI.